# how to insert the result of dbms_output.put_line to a table for error catch?

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
Exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN
--dbms_output.put_line('pl_update_sidm_user r: ERROR CODE:' || sqlcode || '~' || 
--sqlerrm || ' EMPL_NBR:' || r.EMPL_NBR);

insert into ERROR_MSG (ERROR_MSG_ID,ERROR_MSG) values (ERROR_MSG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL, 'pl_update_sidm_user_duty_role r2');
END;
```

I would like to put the error result to a table.
However, how can I do that?

Can I put the result of `dbms_output` to a table as a string?

If not, can I get the `sqlcode,sqlerrm` without using `dbms_output`?

Thank you !!

Comment: You should fix the question title in order to make it more useful for other people facing the same problem; you are not asking how to insert the output of dbms_output: you are asking how to log errors in a table... that's not the same thing

Answer (score 2):

From the **[documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS848)**,

> A SQL statement cannot invoke SQLCODE or SQLERRM. To use their values
>   in a SQL statement, assign them to local variables first

Also,

> Oracle recommends using DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK except when using the FORALL statement with its SAVE EXCEPTIONS clause

So, for `SQLCODE` or `SQLERRM`, you should assign them into variables and use them.

```
DECLARE
v_errcode NUMBER;
v_errmsg VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
--some other statements that may raise exception.
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
v_errcode := SQLCODE;
v_errmsg  := SQLERRM;
insert into ERROR_TABLE (ERROR_MSG_ID,ERROR_MSG) --change your table name
values (ERROR_MSG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
      v_errcode||':'||v_errmsg); 

END;
/
```

Preferably use  insert like this instead, as per Oracle's recommendation.

```
insert into ERROR_TABLE (ERROR_MSG_ID,ERROR_MSG) values (ERROR_MSG_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
      DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_STACK);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8de9840ad7c56e956e04c49920d85b6b)

Answer (score 1):

Technically what others are suggesting is correct: the "insert" operation executed in the "exception when others" block will actually insert a new row in the log table.

**the problem is that such insert statement will be part of the same transaction of the main procedure** and, since you had an error while executing it, **you are very likely to rollback that transaction, and this will rollback also the insert in your log table**

I suppose the problem you are facing is not that you aren't successfully logging the error message: it is that you are rolling it back immediately afterwards, along with all the other writes you did in the same transaction.

Oracle gives you a way of executing code in a SEPARATE transaction, by using "autonomous transaction" procedures.

you need to create such a procedure:

```
create or replace  procedure Write_Error_log(
              arg_error_code number, 
              arg_error_msg varchar2, 
              arg_error_backtrace varchar2) is
 PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
 begin
    INSERT INTO error_msg (
          error_msg_id, 
          error_code, 
          error_msg, 
          error_stack)
     VALUES (
          error_msg_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 
          arg_error_code,
          arg_error_msg,  
          arg_error_backtrace);
     commit; -- you have to commit or rollback always, before exiting a 
             -- pragma autonomous_transaction procedure
 end;
```

What this procedure does is to write a new record in the log table using a totally separate and independent transaction: the data will stay in the log table even if you execute a roll back in your calling procedure.  You can also use such a procedure to create a generic log (not only errors).

All you have to do now is to call the procedure above whenever you need to log something, so your code becomes:

```
DECLARE
   v_errcode NUMBER;
   v_errmsg VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   --some other statements that may raise exception.
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
     Write_Error_log(SQLCODE, SQLERRM, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
END;
/
```

P.S: there might be some typos in my code: I can't test it right now since I can't reach an oracle server in this moment.